# Разложить данные одной таблицы по данным другой таблицы, связанных косвенно

Tags: sql, select

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** имеется БД со следующей структурой
[image: Структура Базы данных - "Режим питания"]

Необходимо разложить каждый прием пищи(таблица Meals) по продуктам(таблица Products) при этом указав общее кол-во продукта входящего в данный прием пищи, его суммарную стоимость и калорийность. Нужно найти обобщенное решение, не зависящее от конкретной СУБД.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:** поскольку эта информация будет часто требоваться, я решил создать представление

```
"CREATE VIEW MEAL_TO_PRODUCTS_STATISTICS " +
                    "(meal_id, product_id, amount_product, total_price, total_calories) AS " +
                    "SELECT " +
                    "MEAL_TO_DISHES_COMPOSITION.meal_id, " +
                    "DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.product_id, " +
                    "SUM(MEAL_TO_DISHES_COMPOSITION.amount_dish * DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.amount_product), " +
                    "SUM(MEAL_TO_DISHES_COMPOSITION.amount_dish * DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.amount_product * PRODUCTS.price), " +
                    "SUM(MEAL_TO_DISHES_COMPOSITION.amount_dish * DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.amount_product * PRODUCTS.calories) " +
                    "FROM " +
                    "MEAL_TO_DISHES_COMPOSITION, DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION, PRODUCTS " +
                    "WHERE MEAL_TO_DISHES_COMPOSITION.dish_id = DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.dish_id AND " +
                    "DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.product_id = PRODUCTS.id " +
                    "GROUP BY MEAL_TO_DISHES_COMPOSITION.meal_id, DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.product_id;"
```

Я проверил его работу на простых наборах данных. Но меня не покидает чувство, что я что-то не учел и возможны случаи, когда этот "запрос" вернет не верные данные. И наверное можно было сделать проще(я новичок в sql).

**Вопрос:** Есть ли ошибки в данном "запросе"? Если есть - то какие? Можно ли оптимизировать решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение можно оптимизировать по скорости используя JOIN. Сам представленный запрос работает верно.